# Why doesn't an interface implemented by a class infer argument types

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

Implementing a few interfaces and a class like this:

```
interface ISecondParameter {
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
}
interface IReturnValue {
    data: number;
}
const o:IReturnValue = {
    data: 5
}
interface IMyClass {
    param1: string;
    method(a:string, b: ISecondParameter): IReturnValue
}

class MyClass implements IMyClass {
    param1
    |
    └──> Member 'param1' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    constructor() {
    }
    method(a, b){
           |  |
           |  └──> Parameter 'b' implicitly has an 'any' type. 
           └──> Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.
        return {
            data: 1
        }
    }
}
```

Gets the errors above. I can remove the errors in `method` by augmenting the arguments list with types ie,

```
method(a: string, b: ISecondParameter) {}
```

And `param1` by putting in the constructor

```
constructor(public param1: string) {}
```

however, this seems redundant. I have already specified the argument types in the function signature in `IMyClass`. Is this redundancy necessary in TypeScript?

Clearly the compiler understands the relationship because

```
const mc = new MyClass()
const result = mc.method('a string', {secondArg: 'john', doesNotConform: 'doe'})
```

will get an error.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?allowUnreachableCode=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUIIPYgCYAKcUcAthJFMgN4BQyDyMIZEAXMgM5hSgDmAbnqMANi3IduvEINoBfWqErwkaAEoUArlBAA1OCM0o6jZHjhg4HEJtIAjaEIU4Q3ZNjaoNYbXoNHkAF4aYQZzSw4AVnlFcGgVFFQAWQBPAGEROE5OENMAB2IyAEZJHn4hU3IwAAtsPAAKKyl%20ABpkOw4MLFxCQqroAEpO7199QwgY2gRM7ORUjKyc4FI8kQhycBzk9Jmck0YCklIi0OQXKU0EMGwoeoHcxgVKilqGuDa7Af3TBigtHQePx%204SsyBOQIYT0eMXOYGQpAQQWQIAgAHc5jtFncprg3H9OJoRHDggiAHRVV71ADkcC4ZRkVLa1E43XwAEEoHwOFSAFbYaogRlmbAQTgAOWwYDSuBgN1I3LwIqpcgGQA)

#### What is the proper way to eliminate this error without having to litter my code with duplicate typings?

Comment: This is a [known design limitation of TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373), apparently relegated to the lonely land of "Won't Fix".  You can read more in there and issues it links to (specifically [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118#issuecomment-216595207)) about why they stopped working on it.  There's a [more recent issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32082) still open and listed as a suggestion, so you might get some traction there.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the links. Can you offer any guidelines regarding how you apply types in situations like this?